# A Better "Your Name Here" Banner Ad?

Tags: discussion, advertising

In the spirit of keeping fresh, interesting banners up on Stack Overflow, I thought I'd try my hand at putting together another "your name here" sort of banner. Here's a rough concept.

[image]

I would have tried making a Superman-like logo thing, but I'm not at the office now, and the only graphic tool I have on this computer is apparently SnagIt.

Thoughts? Suggestions? Ideas?

**EDIT**: This is advertising the advertising on SO. So, a meta-ad if you will.

Comment: Does it show the text "iStockPhoto" in that image? ;-)

Comment: You're advertising what angle? The people putting ads on SO or about SO?

Comment: @random: It's for the advertising program... not for SO it self.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[alt text http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/8258/newestquestionsstackove.png](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/8258/newestquestionsstackove.png)

---

**Edit:** As per Alex's comment:

[alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/2465/adadk.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/2465/adadk.png)          [alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5813/adad2.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5813/adad2.png)

---

**Update:** I just noticed that Alex has recently moved the words to the right. It now looks like this:

[alt text http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/reach_devs2.png](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/reach_devs2.png)

I want to stress that I strongly disagree with this decision (although it's obviously Alex' choice to make), and that this is not the ad I made.

Comment: Ha, *a la* "There's an app for that."  I like it.

Comment: I like it! I could see changing the top part of the copy to "want to reach top developers" or something, as to really nail the point that it's for advertising inquiries.

Comment: Wow, thanks - didn't expect *you* to make the edit -- I'll get it up and running ASAP!

Comment: @Alex: I was curious. You were right; although it's not as subtle, it's probably better. Also: *That* change wasn't exactly a day's worth of work :-)

Comment: Cool,      it's up!

Comment: Grats, that's pretty cool!

Comment: After running for a few days, they're definitely kicking ass (compared to old ad) in terms of clicks. Interesting FYI: "Developers" performes 12% better than "Devs". I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

The Clark Kent shirt opening to reveal superman costume thing has been done sooooo many times in advertisements.

Comment: I think that's why he asks...

Comment: and your suggestion is...?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative text suggestion for the current "Want to reach top devs?": "Top developers could see your ad here." broken into two lines - "Top developers" on the first line, then the logo, then "could see your ad here".

Having only one text doesn't attract as much attention as would having different texts used with the very same black square and logo. Also IMO it's better to start with something absolutely positive. "Top developers" are absolutely positive - what could be better? But "Want to..." leaves the door open to saying "No, thanks" and this is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the current "Want to reach top devs?" is good except that the text is placed suboptimally. Black margings on the left of the captions are muuuch wider than on the right and that makes the ad a bit imperfect.

It'd be much better to have both captions moved to the right a bit (about 10 pixels) so that the margins on both sides don't differ so much. Of course alignment should not be changed in any way - both captions should be moved to the right unchanged and for the very same offset.

Comment: I disagree (but that was to be expected :) ) -- the ad is far from perfect, but the text placement is the one thing I think I got pretty much right. There's no need to have everything centered (as in: left and right margins are equal).

Comment: @balpha: I don't mean everything centered - I only mean move all the text to the right. What purpose does the Big Black Field on the Right serve now?