# Wordpress Side-Bar Advertisement for Serverfault

Tags: feature-request

When taking a look at statcounter.com for my blog I noticed a a few hits that came from expert-exchange...

Could you supply a small image that would fit into the sidebar of most Wordpress templates that is an advertisement for serverfault that is maybe something like:

"Using Expert's Exchange? Stop. Check out Serverfault." (Or maybe just an image add that says what serverfault is)

Or something like that but maybe more clever.  That way any bloggers who want to advertise serverfault (or any of your sites for that matter) can place an ad for it if we want to (for free of course).

I know there is the flare rep thing that you can post, but maybe a more direct ad would be nice.

Comment: Actually, was there one of these for serverfault on stackoverflow? I remember there was a banner, but maybe a side one as well.  That would probably be okay if given permission to use it...

Comment: now that you are working there, maybe you might consider posting all the ads images somewhere on http://sstatic.net/ or somewhere else where people could link to them?  It might be useful if someone where to create a page of side-bar ad images for each SE site that someone could link to in their blog along with their flair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this images here [A Better "Your Name Here" Banner Ad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15990/a-better-your-name-here-banner-ad/16064#16064) but aimed at server fault audience?

I just noticed this image on stackoverflow.  Perhaps this will work.

[serverfault ad http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/try-serverfault.png](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/try-serverfault.png)

Comment: Spot on (if it were serverfault).

Comment: @Kyle Brandt, updated with a link to an ad image that I saw on  stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know - I like the sentiment, but for the SO team itself to produce the content feels tacky.

Comment: Sites have been making their own standard-sized linkback images for decades, man. Are you saying that those decades worth of images is tacky? Because I think those might be fightin' words.

Comment: Yes, but it's tacky to attack the other site in the ad.  They could just do a positive statement linking back to the sites.

Comment: Ya, doesn't have to anti-expert's exchange.  Just an image  add that says what serverfault is... I was more just telling the story of what made me think of it.  The problem with the flair is that nobody would know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm for it sentiment-wise as well, but....  I'd say to post your flair instead and put a little blurb by your flair.

Comment: It is a good idea.  But, it sure would be nice If I could use the flair in a hosted blog/site.  (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/)